# EmberJS transition error route undefined when user changes URL manually

Tags: ember.js

I've been trying to debug this problem for a while and can't seem to find out why my application crashes.
I have the following router:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('post', {path: 'post/:id'});
});
```

and the corresponding route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('post', params.id);    
  },
});
```

if the user goes to `localhost:4200/post/1`, all is fine. But if the user **manually** changes the route to `localhost:4200/post/2`, I get the following stack trace:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'endTime' of undefined
    at TransitionData.routeFinishedSetup (transition-data.js:50)
    at routeWillRender (ember-perf.js:124)
    at renderTemplate (route.js:14)
    at superWrapper [as renderTemplate] (ember.debug.js:21573)
    at _emberRuntimeSystemObject.default.extend.setup (ember.debug.js:26400)
    at Object.callHook (ember.debug.js:50998)
    at handlerEnteredOrUpdated (ember.debug.js:49778)
    at setupContexts (ember.debug.js:49742)
    at finalizeTransition (ember.debug.js:49924)
    at ember.debug.js:49359
```

I tried looking at the code in routeFinishedSetup and it seems that `this.routes` is an empty array.

Through some debugging, I found that this error does not happen anymore IF i change the model function such that it does not call the **store**. For example, if I implement a custom promise here it works fine. 
How can I debug this issue further or if anyone can propose a solution? Thanks!

EDIT:

So after the user manually changes the URL, the new model is correctly retrieved, but the code breaks at the route-rendering step

Comment: Your model name should be singular, so it should be `this.store.findRecord('post', params.id)`. It is also an Ember convention to define the dynamic segment as `modelname_property`, so `this.route('posts', { path: 'post/:post_id' });`. Let me know if the first part solved your problem.

Comment: @locks Thanks for the reply, I refactored the naming so that I use 'post' instead of 'posts' and changed the back-end accordingly. I also changed the dynamic segment name but none of this seemed to solve the issue. Edited the question with more details

Comment: That's a very strange error. Which versions are you using?

Comment: version: 1.13.8
node: 0.12.6
npm: 2.13.4

Answer (score 0):

This might sound like it has nothing to do with your problem.
But if it isn't already change the locationType attribute in environment.js to 'hash'.
Also is that your complete route.js?
Because the error seems to be occurring at route.js:14.
Try to provide a fiddle or twiddle.

Comment: thanks for the reply; route.js is part of ember.debug.js. none of the files in the stack trace is my own, also my locationtyoe is already set to hash

Comment: too bad...there is not much I can do without actually running the code and debugging it live...

Comment: Is there a way to force refresh when the user changes URL? When I reload the page it works

Comment: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/routing/query-params/#toc_opting-into-a-full-transition

Comment: Try the above link. I hope it works.Else you will need to go for a hard refresh like this:window.location.reload(true);